# The correct way to measure tcp performance between ec2 instances

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, testing, networking, amazon-ec2

I used qperf tool to measure the latency between AWS EC2 instances. First I tested tcp latency between two c5xlarge instances and I got latency of 30 micro seconds. Later I terminated those instance and try the test in new two c5xlarge instances. There I got latency of 65 micro seconds. What could be reason for this deviation of results?

Note: There were some other instances in the VPC I created my test instances.

What would be the correct methodology to conduct this kind of test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of instances in a VPC would not impact this metric. All networking is virtual. First, make sure the instances are in the same Availability Zone.

Then, you could try using a [Placement Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html) with the **Cluster** option:

> Packs instances close together inside an Availability Zone. This strategy enables workloads to achieve the **low-latency network performance** necessary for tightly-coupled node-to-node communication that is typical of HPC applications.

Comment: That really worked like a charm. With placement group I was able to decrease the latency to 14 microseconds from 63-65 microseconds (Set the tuned profile to network-latency). Are there any other suggestions to decrease the latency further more? Anyways thank you so much for the help

Comment: Since you're using a C5, just make sure the AMI has the Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) drivers.